# Uninstalling MAMP PRO from my mac

Tags: macos, mamp

I tried to download and set up MAMP on my Mac. When I went to launch, it said that a version of MAMP Pro was installed, and that there may be a conflict having both. I therefore tried to run the uninstall wizard for the MAMP Pro but it gave me an error message and said it had to abort. **Is there another way to get MAMP pro off my computer?**  I tried dragging the folder to the trash and it said it couldn't be deleted.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're on an administrator account.

Download this and follow it's instructions on deleting entire application and it's related files and folders.

http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/

Comment: thank you. Is administrator account in my Mac? or at freemacsoft?

Comment: If your username on your Mac is the only one, then most likely, your account is an administrator account.

Download the application from that site, run and install it.

Comment: but I meant, which account are you talking about? Are you referring to an account on my actual computer?

Comment: Yes. The one on your computer.