# How do I uninstall MAMP Pro

Tags: mamp, uninstallation

Caveat: I'm still realatively new to the Mac and OS X.

I downloaded MAMP from mamp.info to install on my late 2012 iMac running OSX 10.8.5.

The installer gave me the choice of installing just MAMP or MAMP and a 2 week trial of MAMP Pro. After installation I saw the following applications had been installed:  MAMP, MAMP Pro, MacGD8p, MySQLWorkbench, and Sequel Pro. I don't know which programs are part of a MAMP Pro "suite", and which come with the free version of MAMP. When I tried to fire up MAMP I saw this message:

“Warning

The configuration software MAMP PRO is installed. We recommend to administer the server only via MAMP PRO, because a concurrent use of both programs can lead to unexpected results”

I didn’t allow MAMP Pro to initialize it’s components and I want to uninstall it and all other applications that are part of the MAMP PRO suite. I read the uninstall instructions at mamp.info  here: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/installation/uninstall.  In this document an uninstaller is referenced which can be found in the “installation image of MAMP PRO”.  However, what I downloaded from mamp.info was an installer, not a DMG file, so I don’t know what image they’re referring to.  Also, none of the other programs that were installed were referenced in this document.

I also found a previous question on this forum here: [Uninstalling MAMP PRO from my mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453654/uninstalling-mamp-pro-from-my-mac) but it’s over three years old, and again none of the other programs that were installed were referenced.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 13):

You should have two folders in your Applications Folder. One will be MAMP and the other MAMP PRO. Inside the MAMP PRO folder you will find the uninstaller for MAMP PRO. Just double click and your on your way. It will leave MAMP behind for you, which is the free version.

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy.  Thank you!

Comment: This is no longer the case. At least not on Mac. Only the MAMP PRO.app file exists. I just deleted it, and that should do the trick.